# List all Volumes of an SMB share on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, samba, smb

I have enabled SMB sharing on a MacBook Pro with an IP address 192.168.128.29.  On another MacBook Pro, I can connect to server with `smb://192.168.128.29/` and after providing the username and password, there is a pop-up window that lists the available volumes for that SMB mount.
[image: Mac SMB Mount Volumes]
However, if I try to map a network drive in Windows 10 with `\\192.168.128.29\` and provide the same username and password, the drive does not mount.

[image]

Interestingly, the drive will mount if I add one of the existing volumes into the path, for example `\\192.168.128.29\Downloads`.

Is there a way, using Command Prompt or Powershell to list all the volumes of the root smb address the way MacOS does?  A user might not be aware of what volumes are and an easy way to confirm the options would be helpful.

Comment: 'However, if I try to map a network drive in Windows 10 with \\192.168.128.29\ ` .. this is nothing but an IP address.  What is it supposed to map to?  Have you tried pasting that IP into the windows explorer and seeing what is there at that point?  You should then be able to right click and map any of the shares that are there.. very much like the finder is doing in the dialog provided (which is also NOT scripted).

Comment: `net[.exe] view \\addr_or_hostname` -- but note shares do not need to be volumes and the ones you show almost certainly aren't, so Apple is wrong to call them so.